# How do I connect to mysql database in Grails?

Tags: mysql, grails, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 mysql database which I connected in my local machine. I have created a database in it named `locker`.

And I uncommented the line in `BuildConfig.groovy` to add mysql connector.

Here is my `DataSource.groovy` file :

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/locker?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "anto"
            password = "****"
        }
        hibernate {
            show_sql = true
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tried to run  my grails app I get an big error like this :

```
 Error 2012-07-05 18:54:53,533 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->> 1549 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by SQLException: Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
->> 1073 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   3597 | checkErrorPacket in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   3529 | checkErrorPacket in     ''
|    935 | checkErrorPacket in     ''
|   4101 | secureAuth411 in     ''
|   1300 | doHandshake in     ''
|   2337 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2370 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2154 | createNewIO in     ''
|    792 | <init>    in     ''
|     47 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    381 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    305 | connect   in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-07-05 18:54:53,630 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR [localhost].[/locker]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
->> 1549 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by SQLException: Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
->> 1073 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   3597 | checkErrorPacket in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   3529 | checkErrorPacket in     ''
|    935 | checkErrorPacket in     ''
|   4101 | secureAuth411 in     ''
|   1300 | doHandshake in     ''
|   2337 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2370 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2154 | createNewIO in     ''
|    792 | <init>    in     ''
|     47 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    381 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    305 | connect   in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-07-05 18:54:53,655 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error listenerStart
| Error 2012-07-05 18:54:53,671 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context [/locker] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I'm very new to grails. What went wrong? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the username and password you are using are not valid:

```
Access denied for user 'anto'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This isn't a Grails problem, it's a general permissions problem.

Comment: I guess I have given the `CIDR/IP` in  amazon Ec2 as `122.***.2**.**/**`. Whether this might be the problem?

Comment: I'm sure that the username and password I'm passing in is correct.

Comment: It's trying to connect to localhost, not the actual server IP address

Comment: @user1500898, it's likely that you don't have the MySQL permissions for that user set up to allow it to connect to/from localhost if you are sure the username/password pair is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348272/connecting-to-remote-mysql-server-using-jdbc-issue) question. It discusses configuring MySQL to allow remote connections and JDBC. You may need to configure MySQL to allow remote connections because the JDBC drive uses TCP/IP sockets to connect to the database regardless of where the database server is running and where the JDBC client is running.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there might be two reasons(or more) of that problem. One is the permission reason, which you should give to your specific user.

Also, I have noticed that in your DataSource.groovy, the url is set to be:
`url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/locker?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"`

Just to notice, you might forget to add your mysql port in the url, which would lead to the same problem. The way I did is like:
`url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/locker:1234?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"`